# I am stuck in writing a loop in assembly to read 5 characters and print them in reverse order

Tags: loops, assembly, dos, x86-16

```
.data

.code
main proc

        mov cx,5
        user_input:
        
        mov ah,1h
        int 21h
        push dx
        
        loop user_input
        
        
        mov cx,5
        system_output:
        
        
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h
        pop dx
        
        loop system_output
    
    
    
    endp
```

I want to write a code that gets 5 numbers from the User and print all five of them in reversed order
my code

the program gets 5 numbers but does nothing and dies.

and I still cant find my numbers in Stack,
and I put the screen shot below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AH=1` function gives you a character in the `AL` register. You should use `push AX` in the first loop! (instead of `push dx`)

In the second loop you should use `pop DX` **before** doing function `AH=2`.

And best end your program with:

```
mov ax, 4C00h
int 21h
```

Comment: You are right dear friend, I am a very beginner in the Assembly language! I thought it was the opposite of printing. And I thought it would save the value of ASCII"2" in dl. Thanks for the explanation, and I did not understand the last part of your comment, can you explain more? What's wrong with the end of the program? thanks again

Comment: @DanialHamedi: The CPU will keep executing bytes of machine code in a straight line, even if that falls off the end of the bytes produced by the assembler and into garbage left in memory after it.  Unless you make an "exit" system call.

Answer (score -1):

section .data
name db 'Your Name', 0
id db 'Your ID', 0

section .text
global _start

_start:
; Set foreground color to cyan (3) and background color to blue (4)
mov eax, 0x4F9A    ; system call for changing color
mov ebx, 3         ; foreground color (cyan)
mov ecx, 4         ; background color (blue)
int 0x80           ; call the kernel

```
; Display name
mov eax, 4         ; sys_write system call
mov ebx, 1         ; file descriptor (stdout)
mov ecx, name      ; message address
mov edx, 9         ; message length
int 0x80           ; call the kernel

; Display newline
mov eax, 4         ; sys_write system call
mov ebx, 1         ; file descriptor (stdout)
mov ecx, newline   ; newline address
mov edx, 1         ; newline length
int 0x80           ; call the kernel

; Display ID
mov eax, 4         ; sys_write system call
mov ebx, 1         ; file descriptor (stdout)
mov ecx, id        ; message address
mov edx, 7         ; message length
int 0x80           ; call the kernel

; Exit the program
mov eax, 1         ; sys_exit system call
xor ebx, ebx       ; exit status
int 0x80           ; call the kernel
```

section .data
newline db 10      ; newline character

Comment: `0x4F9A` (`20378`) isn't a Linux system call number.  `asm/unistd_32.h` only has call numbers from `1` to `450` on my system (Linux kernel 6.5).  Also, this is a 16-bit DOS question, and it's not asking for code to just print string constants.